# ContextMenuStrip ToolStripLabel Image in wrong place

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I have a tray icon with a context menu.  I'm adding things to the `ContextMenuStrip` such as `ToolStripLabel`.  I want the label to have an icon all the way on the left.  However, the icon is displayed on the right side of the menu item with the text.  Code sample:

```
        // Create the context menu
        trayContextMenu_ = new ContextMenuStrip();

        // Add a header
        ToolStripLabel headerLabel = new ToolStripLabel(Config.AppName);
        headerLabel.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 48, 113, 169);
        headerLabel.Image = global::MillApp.Properties.Resources.icon_32;
        headerLabel.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        trayContextMenu_.Items.Insert(0, headerLabel);
        trayContextMenu_.Items.Insert(1, new ToolStripSeparator());

        notifyIcon_.ContextMenuStrip = trayContextMenu_;
```

[image: tray menu]

Comment: This is not a WPF question. `ContextMenuStrip` and `NotifyIcon`) are part of WinForms.

Comment: It looks like this might be a limitation of ToolStripLabel.  Real menu items display the image on the left side using the same code.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279077/image-layout-toolstriplabel-c-sharp